# wordpress website is redirecting to blink.piterreceiver.ga/fast.php?t=j&id=658-3474568568-23-458578434

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress website Awannews.fr is being redirect to blink.piterreceiver.ga/fast.php?t=j&id=658-3474568568-23-458578434. Can someone please help how can i figure out whats the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the exact same redirect happening on a WordPress website I worked on. What worked for me was disabling a plugin that came with the theme I'm using on the site. In my case, it was an outdated version of the "*WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts*" plugin that was infected with some malicious code.

Once I found the specific page the redirect happened on, I opened Inspect Elements in the Browser and looked at the changes to the page while it loaded in. There I managed to catch a glimpse of a `<div>` element loading in just before it redirects (the element id was pointing back to the plugin I ended up disabling).

**First, I would recommend to:**

1. Make sure all of the WordPress plugins are up to date.
2. Try to disable one plugin at a time and then refresh, check the site itself in another tab or window to see if the problem still presists.

If the 2 steps above don't help, then you could try to narrow down the cause/source by going around your WordPress site and try to catch at which point or which specific page the redirect happens. That way you could have a better idea of where to look or where not to look for the cause.

I hope this is helpful and you can post an update on how it went.